# Tycho can't resolve javax.rmi after switching to Java-11

Tags: eclipse, java-11, tycho

I'm trying to switch our legacy multi-modules project to Java-11, but tycho complaints on missing dependencies
in my pom file, I added JDK version as 11. Here is part of pom

```
...
 <properties>
    
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <jdk-version>11</jdk-version>
    <!-- Plugins tycho version -->
    <tycho.version>1.7.0</tycho.version>
...
 </properties>
<build>
...
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
        <artifactId>tycho-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${tycho.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>${jdk-version}</source>
          <target>${jdk-version}</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
...
</build>
```

And here is my META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Meta-Persistence: META-INF/openjpa_persistence_product.xml
Bundle-Name: JPA
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.XXX.jpa
Bundle-Version: 2.1.2
Bundle-Vendor: XXX
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-11
Eclipse-ExtensibleAPI: true
Import-Package: com.XXX.config,
 com.XXX.core,
 com.XXX.core.util.logging,
 com.XXX.sql,
 javax.persistence,
 javax.persistence.criteria,
 javax.persistence.metamodel,
 org.apache.openjpa.persistence,
 org.apache.openjpa.util,
 org.osgi.framework,
 org.osgi.service.component,
 org.osgi.service.jdbc,
 org.osgi.service.jndi,
 org.osgi.service.jpa,
 org.slf4j
Export-Package: com.XXX.jpa,
 com.XXX.jpa.concurrent,
 com.XXX.jpa.util
Service-Component: OSGI-INF/*.xml
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
```

After executed mvn clean install I received

```
ERROR] Cannot resolve project dependencies:
[ERROR]   Software being installed: com.XXX.jpa 2.1.2
[ERROR]   Missing requirement: org.apache.openjpa 3.0.0 requires 'java.package; javax.rmi 0.0.0' but it could not be found
[ERROR]   Cannot satisfy dependency: com.XXX.jpa 2.1.2 depends on: java.package; org.apache.openjpa.persistence 0.0.0
```

What I tried

1. add version to  org.apache.openjpa.persistence, org.apache.openjpa.util in MANIFEST.MF
2. add javax.rmi into Import-Package section of MANIFEST.MF

But result was always the same - tycho complaints on javax.rmi package

**UPDATE**
Hi @howlger! Thanks for your help, but now I received another problem

1. I create bunlde for javax.rmi

```
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.XXX</groupId>
    <artifactId>bundle.platform</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
  </parent>
  
  <!-- This bundle was added because in Java-11 javax.rmi package was removed from the standard library -->
  <groupId>com.XXX</groupId>
  <artifactId>com.XXX.javax.rmi</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.6.Final</version>
  <packaging>bundle</packaging>
  <name>Java RMI API Bundle</name>
  
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.rmi</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-rmi-api_1.0_spec</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
          <instructions>
            <Export-Package>
              *;version="${project.version}"
            </Export-Package>
            <Import-Package>
              *
            </Import-Package>
            <Embed-Dependency>*;scope=compile|runtime;inline=true</Embed-Dependency>
            <Bundle-SymbolicName>
              ${project.artifactId}
            </Bundle-SymbolicName>
          </instructions>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

and deployed to our artifactory, but unfortunately can't add this bundle to p2 feature

I added it as a dependency to main pom file which creates p2 repo as

```
 <dependencies>
 <!-- com.XXX.javax.rmi -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.rmi</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-rmi-api_1.0_spec</artifactId>
      <version>${javax.rmi.version}</version>
    </dependency>    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.rmi</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-rmi-api_1.0_spec</artifactId>
      <version>${javax.rmi.version}</version>
      <classifier>sources</classifier>
    </dependency>
 </dependencies>
```

But when I'm trying to add that bundle to platform feature as a plugin

```
<plugin
        id="com.XXX.javax.rmi"
        download-size="0"
        install-size="0"
        version="0.0.0"
        unpack="false"/>
```

I received:

```
[ERROR] Cannot resolve project dependencies:
[ERROR]   Software being installed: com.XXX.repository 2.1.2
[ERROR]   Missing requirement: com.XXX.bundle.platform.feature.feature.group 2.1.2 requires 'org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; com.navteq.javax.rmi 0.0.0' but it could not be found
[ERROR]   Cannot satisfy dependency: com.navteq.phoenix.repository 2.1.2 depends on: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; com.navteq.phoenix.bundle.platform.feature.feature.group [2.1.2,2.1.3)
[ERROR]
```

What I do incorrect?

**UPDATE2**
There were 2 main problem in this issue

1. Incorrect dependency in main pom file which creates p2 repo - it should have the same groupId, artifactId, version as the ones in pom which creates bandle

```
<dependencies>
 <!-- com.XXX.javax.rmi -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.XXX</groupId>
      <artifactId>com.XXX.javax.rmi</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>
 </dependencies>
```

2. The import of the sun.refelection should be added to pom file which created bundle

```
<configuration>
  <instructions>
    <Export-Package>
      *;version="${project.version}"
    </Export-Package>
    <Import-Package>
      sun.reflect;resolution:=optional
    </Import-Package>
    <Embed-Dependency>*;scope=compile|runtime;inline=true</Embed-Dependency>
    <Bundle-SymbolicName>
      ${project.artifactId}
    </Bundle-SymbolicName>
  </instructions>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [**`javax.rmi`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/rmi/package-summary.html) package was contain **in the system library** (in Java 9 and 10 in the module [`java.corba`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java.corba-summary.html)) **until** it was removed in **Java 11** by [JEP 320](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/320).

For Java 11 or higher you need to **add a plugin/bundle** containing the package `javax.rmi` **to your target platform** since it is required by the `org.apache.openjpa` plugin/bundle you have. Or maybe there is a newer version of `org.apache.openjpa` that contains the `javax.rmi` package or does not require it anymore.

Comment: Hi @howlger, could you please look at UPDATE in my post?

Comment: Deployed to your Artifactory as a Maven artifact or as an Eclipse p2 install unit? Please show also your [target definition file](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html#exercise-using-a-target-platform-for-the-build). IMHO instead of the update, you should ask this as a separate question with the [artifactory] tag (I have no experience with Artifactory).

Comment: where do you get the bundle?

Comment: @Mr.Mundkowsky I don't see it in the 2021-09 release nor in Orbit, only as [non-OSGi bundle](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.spec.javax.rmi/jboss-rmi-api_1.0_spec/1.0.6.Final). If no one provides it, you'll have to build it yourself.